# Promise not returning complete info from function

Tags: typescript, react-native, promise, async-await

I have a function that completes two await tasks, one that grabs info from a database in the cloud, another that grabs the users location. The function should return a promise that contains the results of both of these tasks. For some reason, `the promise will only return the result of the first await (database...), not the second (Geolocation...)`. Here is some code that is related to the problem.

```
async function grabUserData(): Promise<Object> {
  const data = {
    position: {Latitude: 0, Longitude: 0},
    altitude: 0,
    altitudeAccuracy: 0,
    timestamp: Timestamp.now(),
    };
  await database
    .collection('users')
    .doc(userUID)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        'does some work here' (which works fine)
      } else {
        console.log('No such document!');
      }
    });
  await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    data.position.Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    data.position.Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    if (position.coords.altitude != null) {
      data.altitude = position.coords.altitude;
    }
    if (position.coords.altitudeAccuracy != null) {
      data.altitudeAccuracy = position.coords.altitudeAccuracy;
    }
  });
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    resolve(data);
  });
}
```

Update: Geolocation.getCurrentPosition does NOT return a promise therefore it shouldn't have await next to it. However, even with removing it, it does not change anything related to the problem I'm having. I actually put it there because I thought by awaiting it, it would not be skipped over and return incomplete data.

Comment: `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition` doesn't return a promise, you can't `await` it.

Comment: Okay, I knew it didnt return a promise, however since in the documentation it said that the method might take a while, I thought if I didnt await it, it would skip over it and return data that was incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're combining two ways of working with Promises in a confusing way... maybe try something like this. Async functions return Promises automatically.

Updated to include the Geolocation promise idea:

```
const getPosition = options => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options);
  });
}

async function grabUserData(): Promise<Object> {
  const data = {
    position: {Latitude: 0, Longitude: 0},
    altitude: 0,
    altitudeAccuracy: 0,
    timestamp: Timestamp.now(),
    };

  const doc = await database
    .collection('users')
    .doc(userUID)
    .get();

  if (doc.exists) {
    'does some work here' (which works fine) 
  } else {
     console.log('No such document!');
  }

  const position = await getPosition()

  data.position.Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  data.position.Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  if (position.coords.altitude != null) {
    data.altitude = position.coords.altitude;
  }
  if (position.coords.altitudeAccuracy != null) {
    data.altitudeAccuracy = position.coords.altitudeAccuracy;
  }

  return data;
}
```

Comment: And it looks like @tkausl is right too... `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` doesn't return a Promise anyway.

Comment: Right I did notice that it didn't return a promise and explained why I put one in a reply to @tkausl, however my thought process was flawed. I am confused on how this would make a difference whether I assign a var/const to the method or not.

Comment: Yeah, it gets confusing mixing promises with callbacks... maybe use a method like this so your Geolocation call can actually be a promise: https://gist.github.com/varmais/74586ec1854fe288d393

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Geolocation.getCurrentPosition() is a promise that returns a `position`?

If that is the case, then you're just missing a `then`. It looks like you pass the function to `getCurrentPosition`

```
await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
    .then((position) => { // move the previous function to then
    data.position.Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    data.position.Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    if (position.coords.altitude != null) {
      data.altitude = position.coords.altitude;
    }
    if (position.coords.altitudeAccuracy != null) {
      data.altitudeAccuracy = position.coords.altitudeAccuracy;
    }
  });
```